# Remove-Msoldomain cmdlet in AzureAD is useless?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, office365

I have a several directories in my Azure Tenant and I am trying to delete one of them. For example, my default directory is contoso.com and I have another directory Farikam.com

By default, when you connect to Azure AD you only have access to that specific tenant. When I execute Connect-MsolSerivce with the credentials admin@contoso.com and run get-msoldomain the only domain that is returned is contoso.com despite this Azure AD Account being a global administration in the consoto and fabrikam domains.

If I attempt to delete fabrikam.com, I am prompted that is domain isn't found. If login with admin@fabrikam.com I am prompted that I can't delete my own domain and need to switch my default domain but there aren't any other domains to switch too!

Answer (score 0):

The `Remove-MsolDomain` is meant to be used to remove domains that have been added to the Office 365 Admin Center's [DOMAINS](https://portal.office.com/admin/default.aspx#DomainManagerPageLayout) panel. Before you can remove a domain, it needs to be removed from all users/distribution groups/conference rooms, etc...

If your tenant has a tenantname.onmicrosoft.com available, you can use that as the user's domain.

Comment: The remove-msoldomain does remove domains from Office 365 however Office 365 uses Azure Active Directory as it's source for Identity and Directory Services. I have removed all users excluding the last administrative user in the directory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194124.aspx

It appears that it isn't possible to delete a domain given the connections are managed with Azure itself. May you show me an example of how'd you connect to MSOL and delete a domain?